# Garbage being printed after last character by putchar

Tags: c, ansi-c

My `putchar()` function is returning garbage after the sum is made.

Here's my code snippet:

```
scanf("%d", & keys);
getchar();
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    c = c + keys;
    putchar(c);
}
puts("");
```

Comment: What are you doing with the `'\n'` left in `stdin` by `scanf("%d", &keys);`? Outputting it is fine, but adding it to `keys` seems a bit wonky if you want to ensure going to get a `char` out of the summation of `c = c + keys;` (which likely exceeds `126` at the end)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin nice, ty, will try

Comment: Always make sure what you pass to `putchar()` falls within the printable range - see: [ASCII Table and Description](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin sorry, forgot to put the extra getchar, but is was already in the code

Comment: Ok, better, then the second part, making sure `' ' <= c <= '~'` before calling `putchar()` -- otherwise funny/weird characters will be output as you are calling `putchar()` on something outside the printable range of ASCII characters.

Comment: Also `c` must be an *`int`*

Answer (score 0):

If I understand where you are going, your problem (the funny characters at the end) are due to your addition of `c = c + keys;` resulting in a character value greater than `126` (e.g. the `'~'` char). For example, if your `keys` is greater than `4` and you input `'z'`, then your resulting `c + keys` is outside the valid range of ASCII characters. See [ASCII Table and Description](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Depending on what you want to do, you can simply use `%` (modulo) to ensure you always have a valid ASCII character before calling `putchar()`. Something like:

```
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        c = (c + keys) % ('~' - ' ' + 1) + ' '; /* use modulo to ensure ASCII */
        putchar (c);
    }
```

(**note:** `'~' - ' ' + 1` is simply the printable range of ASCII values -- `95` chars - thanks Roland)

Putting together a guess at a short example program that appears to be where you are going, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* simple helper function to remove to end of line */
void empty_line (void)
{
    int c = getchar();

    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();
}

int main (void) {

    int c, keys;

    if (scanf("%d", & keys) != 1 || keys < 0) { /* Validate EVERY Input! */
        fputs ("error: invalid or negative integer input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    empty_line();

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        c = (c + keys) % ('~' - ' ' + 1) + ' '; /* use modulo to ensure ASCII */
        putchar (c);
    }
    putchar ('\n');     /* not puts, you need 1-char, not string */
}
```

(**note:** you must ***Validate*** every input, *especially* when using `scanf` to perform a conversion to `int` -- or any other type)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/putcharmod
33
My dog has zero fleas, my cat has none :)
/[aFQIaJCUa\GTQaHNGCUmaO[aECVaJCUaPQPGa{jK
```

Above, despite having `keys = 33`, inputting `'z'` results in no funny characters as the total `c + keys` is reduced to within the printable range of characters.

Of course adjust the scheme to meet whatever your end objective happens to be, but regardless, if you are outputting to `stdout` with `putchar()`, you will need to do something similar to make sure what you output is printable.

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: There are only 2 hard problems in programming: cache invalidation and naming things. And off-by-one errors. (in the %)

Comment: Note: `c = (c + keys) % ('~' - ' ' + 1) + ' ';` does not to ensure ASCII not when `c + keys < 0`

Comment: Right you are. I guess we need an `abs` in there somewhere. Will just require `keys > 0` until we hear more is needed.